# Fluent NHibernate and automapping generic types

Tags: generics, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm automapping most of my model, but have a problem with generics.
I've got `ValueContainer<TValue>`, and I make it abstract so that it
doesn't throw an exception during automapping. Next, I have to create
classes like `StringValueContainer` just to make it mapped. Needless to
say, I don't like this approach, since I'm perfectly happy with the
generic classes.

So, the question is, how do I manually map classes like
`ValueContainer<string>` that inherit from an automapped class? I tried
to fluently configure the subclass via SubclassMap, but that,
predictably, failed.

Just to clarify: I've got `StringValueContainer: ValueContainer<string>`, but the `StringValueContainer` class doesn't add any value except for automapping, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: How would you map this with HBM?

Comment: <joined-subclass name="ValueContainer`1[System.String]" extends="ValueContainer" table="StringValueContainer">
  <key>
   <column name="ValueContainer_id" />
  </key>
  <property name="Value" />
 </joined-subclass>

Comment: Although I finished working on this project a year ago..